Firestore Database Query
I have a button created in code that calls the function:
@objc func settingsButtonTapped() async {
    print("settings button tapped")
    await self.getMultipleAll()
}

I copied and pasted the documentation from Firestore:
private func getMultipleAll() async {
   // [START get_multiple_all]
   do {
       let querySnapshot = try await self.db.collection("cities").getDocuments()
     for document in querySnapshot.documents {
       print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
     }
   } catch {
     print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
   }
   // [END get_multiple_all]
 }

Here's the link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=en&authuser=0
Every time I try to run this it crashes and goes to the App Delegate. It's copied and pasted from google. Any help?
Error message:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
It crashes before even "settings buttons tapped" prints.
It's like Google doesn't want cloud customers.

"it crashes" is really hard to help with. Do. you have any error message?

Updated with the error message. The code is copied and pasted from the Firestone documentation.
